# Subtracting user entered value from a set value

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I want to be able to subtract the user entered value from a text box from the set value I have set within a different class, i am a beginner at programming and willing to learn more tips and tricks throughout c#

```
private void ContinueBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( TravelTypeTXT.Text == "First Class")
    {
        Seating.FirstClass -= Convert.ToInt32(PassengersTXT);
        if (Seating.FirstClass <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Seats in First Class", "ERROR!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
Seating.FirstClass -= Convert.ToInt32(PassengersTXT);
```

should be this:

```
Seating.FirstClass -= Convert.ToInt32(PassengersTXT.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that earlier and it kept giving me errors, i was trying all different covert to tin or convert to string to get it to work